# MS Graph C# Library UserRequest.GetAsync exits prematurely without any information

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, console-application

I am making this request using the MS Graph C# Library:

```cs
var userRequest= _msGraphServiceClient.Users[email].Request()
    .Select("givenName,surname,id,extension_removed_uuid_employeeID");
try
{
    Console.WriteLine("Making the request now....");
    return await userRequest.GetAsync();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Oops something happened");
    Console.WriteLine(e);
    throw;
}
Console.WriteLine("How did I end up here?");
```

The method is marked as "async Task."

In the console, I see this:

```
Making the request now....
C:\p\Cleanup\bin\Debug\net5.0\Cleanup.exe (process 30804) exited with code 0.
```

Then I get the message to close the window.

Comment: When the control reaches `await`, the main control is passed back to the caller which might result in exit (since console app assuming without other task in line).  [more read..](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await)

Comment: Please share the whole method and how do you call this method.